# Playwright stealth

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, playwright

I have been using puppeteer for a while, but decided to convert to playwright. In puppeteer, there was a plugin `puppeteer-extra-stealth` which was able to hide headless chrome and websites did not detect headless mode. Is there a similar thing for playwright?

Comment: Playwright is focused on UI testing. If you want to scrape website I would keep using Puppeteer.

Comment: @hardkoded I'm more comfortable using puppeteer to be honest, but it has some issues now and websites that I want to log in and scrape from detect botting. It is not only me, but the entire puppeteer community, that is why I wanted to convert to playwright temporary and tackle not being detected headless, while puppeteer are fixing this.

Answer (score 9):

There is a `playwright-extra` in development however according to the creator this won't include the stealth evasions.
See: https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/pull/303 for more information.

That being said, you don't really need an external package in order to implement functionality that the `puppeteer-extra-stealth` package offers. Here is my attempt: https://gist.github.com/nicoandmee/1ec1b6a07c94f82df41d2496194ef3a6

In addition to doing everything the puppeteer package is doing, my code is generating a unique browser fingerprint based on real data collected from google analytics. This fingerprint is then used as part of the "evasions." It should be sufficient for most use-cases.

Answer (score 4):

The [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) plugin [has been ported to Playwright](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/playwright-extra#-puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth).

Comment: Have you managed to use it with codegen? i.e. `npx playwright codegen www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

There is [playwright-stealth](https://pypi.org/project/playwright-stealth/), but it uses python. With that said, the API for playwright is very similar across languages, shouldn't be very hard to port it to the one you want to use it in.